# I am trying to solve the inequality $\log_{\log{\sqrt{9-x^2}}} x^2 <0$

Tags: inequality, logarithms

I am trying to solve  the inequality

$$\log_{\log{\sqrt{9-x^2}}}   x^2 <0.$$

I got $\mathrm{S.S}=(-\sqrt8 ,-1)\cup( 1,\sqrt8)$, but a friend  got  $\mathrm{S.S}=(-1,1)- \{0\}$.

Please, what is true?

Comment: is the base of the first logarithm a natural log or a log base 10?

Comment: Do you mean $\log_{\log{\sqrt{9-x^2}}}{ x^2} <0$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We shall consider two cases:

(1) **Case** ($\log \sqrt {9-x^2} >1$)

$$\log_{\log \sqrt{9-x^2}} x^2 <0 \Rightarrow $$

$$\left \{
\begin{array}{l}
0 \neq x^2 < 1 \\
\log \sqrt {9-x^2} >1 \\
\end{array}
\right. \Leftrightarrow
\left \{
\begin{array}{l}
-1 < x < 1 \quad \mathrm {and} \quad x\neq 0\\
\sqrt {9-x^2} > 10 \\
\end{array}
\right. \Leftrightarrow $$
$$ \Leftrightarrow
\left \{
\begin{array}{l}
-1 < x < 1 \quad \mathrm {and} \quad x\neq 0\\
-x^2 > 91 \\
\end{array}
\right. \Leftrightarrow
\left \{
\begin{array}{l}
-1 < x < 1 \quad \mathrm {and} \quad x\neq 0\\
x^2 < -91 \\
\end{array}
\right. \Leftrightarrow $$
$$ \Leftrightarrow S = \emptyset $$

(2) **Case** ($0 < \log \sqrt {9-x^2} < 1$)

$$\log_{\log \sqrt{9-x^2}} x^2 <0 \Rightarrow $$

$$\left \{
\begin{array}{l}
x^2 > 1 \\
0 < \log \sqrt {9-x^2} <1 \\
\end{array}
\right. \Leftrightarrow
\left \{
\begin{array}{l}
x< -1 \quad \mathrm{or} \quad x > 1\\
1< \sqrt {9-x^2} < 10 \\
\end{array}
\right. \Leftrightarrow $$
$$ \Leftrightarrow
\left \{
\begin{array}{l}
x< -1 \quad \mathrm {or} \quad x > 1\\
1< 9-x^2 < 100 \\
\end{array}
\right. \Leftrightarrow
\left \{
\begin{array}{l}
x< -1 \quad \mathrm {or} \quad x > 1\\
-8< -x^2 < 91 \\
\end{array}
\right. \Leftrightarrow $$
$$ \Leftrightarrow
\left \{
\begin{array}{l}
x< -1 \quad \mathrm {or} \quad x > 1\\
8>\ x^2 > -91 \\
\end{array}
\right. \Leftrightarrow
\left \{
\begin{array}{l}
x< -1 \quad \mathrm {or} \quad x > 1\\
-\sqrt{8}< x < \sqrt{8} \\
\end{array}
\right. \Leftrightarrow $$
$$ \Leftrightarrow S = (-\sqrt{8},-1) \cup (1,\sqrt{8}) $$
Therefore you are right and not your friend.

Comment: @Ahmed. You're welcome:)

Answer (score 3):

$$\log_{\log_c(\sqrt{9-x^2})}x^2=\frac{\log_b x^2}{\log_b(\log_c\sqrt{9-x^2})}<0 $$

Without any loss of generality, we can take base $b>1$

(i)If  $\log_b x^2<0 \iff x^2<1$

then we need 
$\log_b(\log_c\sqrt{9-x^2})>0\implies \log_c\sqrt{9-x^2}>1\implies x^2<9-c^2$

$\implies x^2<min(1,9-c^2)$

Here observe that for real $x, min(1,9-c^2)>x^2>0\implies 9-c^2>0\implies c^2<9$ else there will be no solution.

(ii)If  $\log_b x^2>0 \iff x^2>1$

then we need $\log_b(\log_c\sqrt{9-x^2})<0\implies\log_c\sqrt{9-x^2}<1\implies x^2>9-c^2$

$\implies x^2>max(1,9-c^2)$